# What is each side of the conflict in the Lord of the Rings trilogy called?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Wherever I look they are always being called "Good" and "Evil".

Are there any canonical names for each side of the conflict?

For example in World War 1 there was the Triple Alliance and the Triple Entente.

Comment: Sauron the Merciful versus the ungrateful peons he wanted to rule

Comment: There's lots of alternate names; The forces of Gondor, Sauron's host, the hosts of Mordor, etc. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Could you give an example of how one might use such a name in a sentence?

Comment: @Valorum but I don't want to use names like those because there were lots of factions involved in conflict and some Elves might be mad about name "The forces of Gondor"

Comment: @jtheletter I have edited my questions with small example

Comment: Who's perspective are we talking about, the winner?

Comment: "The even more last alliance" versus "Mini-Morgoth and friends".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Sauron and the Free Peoples

The War of the Ring was mostly fought between two sides, Tolkien often named these sides *Sauron* and the *Free Peoples of Middle-earth*. This sentiment is most clearly covered in Robert Foster's *Complete Guide to Middle-earth*

> **War of the Ring** - The great war fought at the end of the Third Age between Sauron and the Free Peoples, the subject of Lord of the Rings. In the War Sauron was overthrown for the final time and the One Ring destroyed...
> <sub>Robert Foster, The Complete Guide to Middle-earth, p. 416, entry "War of the Ring"</sub>

Christopher Tolkien, in the *Unfinished Tales* called the above resource *"an admirable work of reference"* (UT, p 4).

The term Free Peoples is repeated several times throughout the *Lord of the Rings*, it's first use was in *The Fellowship of the Ring*, wherein which Elrond describes the Fellowship as representing the races of the Free Peoples:

> ‘The Company of the Ring shall be Nine; and the Nine Walkers shall be set against the Nine Riders that are evil. With you and your faithful servant, Gandalf  will  go;  for  this  shall  be  his  great  task,  and  maybe  the  end  of  his labours.
>
> ‘For the rest, they shall represent the **other Free Peoples of the World**: Elves, Dwarves, and Men.
> <sub>Fellowship of the Ring - Book II, Chapter III: The Ring Goes South</sub>

As for the side of evil, most commonly used to refer to them is simply the term "Sauron". While this isn't exactly accurate as Saruman attempted to be a player in the War as well, he was never a powerful force and was disposed of rather quickly. Saruman was also under the sway of Sauron. The use of the term "Sauron" to fight the enemy is likely due to the control he possessed over his armies, as none acted without his command or his thought.

Comment: The explanation of why *"Sauron"* is used to describe the bad side as a whole makes a lot of sense. It's similar to the WWII usage of *"Fighting Hitler"*.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd one must remember that Tolkien intended no allegory and that is merely a coincidence (although likely trickled about in the profs mind) but yes I guess it would be the same idea!

Comment: He served in the WWII though

Comment: He served in World War 1, not 2.

Comment: @BernardtheBear The Professor served in the Great War, but his Son, Christopher certainly sent him letters from occupied France and Germany in the second World War (IIRC). I’m also unsure how the war he served in is relevant, the allegory is still entirely unintentional.

Comment: @Edlothiad if there are Free People, may I use term Enslaved People for the evil side?

Comment: @ChrisK. No, they weren’t necessarily enslaved. The free peoples are free from the evils of Sauron and his master, Morgoth, not just free from slavery.

Answer (score -2):

The Lord of the Rings Online MMOG refers to the Free People Of Middle-earth and to Creepers, leading to the commonly-used abbreviations "freeps and creeps".

Comment: This is not in any way canonical.

Comment: Well half of it is. The Free Peoples was used as a term for those opposed to Sauron.  The Creepers part is not though.

Comment: Sauron: "Hey now wait just a minute..."